# Traceroute on Linux doesn't work properly

Tags: linux, terminal, packets, traceroute

I am trying to find out how many hops are required to reach google.com using traceroute. Traceroute's output is always the same.
My command: `traceroute google.com`
Output:

```
traceroute to google.com (194.249.4.237), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1 10.0.2.2 0.123 ms 0.063 ms 0.172 ms
2 10.0.2.2 4.570 ms 4.661 ms 9.793 ms
```

I don't think it works properly... Can someone help me please? Thank you in beforehand.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: I assume this output is not correct since I get the same output for every destination I type instead of google.com. Also I found an exact same example with google.com and there were many more hops than two.

Comment: `whois 10.0.2.2`: These addresses are in use by many millions of independently operated networks, which might be as small as a single computer connected to a home gateway, and are automatically configured in hundreds of millions of devices.  They are only intended for use within a private context  and traffic that needs to cross the Internet will need to use a different, unique address.

Comment: So what do I have to do exactly? Change IP address that my virtual box uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely behind a strong firewall. Use `man traceroute` to check out other methods you can use to get your result.

Comment: I added the flag -I to use ICMP ECHO for probes and got the desired output.